# Using asymmetric encryption to secure passwords

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, rsa

Due to our customer's demands, user passwords must be kept in some "readable" form in order to allow accounts to be converted at a later date. Unfortunately, just saving hash values and comparing them on authentication is not an option here. Storing plain passwords in the database is not an option either of course, but using an encryption scheme like AES might be one. But in that case, the key to decrypt passwords would have to be stored on the system handling authentication and I'm not quite comfortable with that.

Hoping to get "best of both worlds", my implementation is now using RSA asymmetric encryption to secure the passwords. Passwords are salted and encrypted using the public key. I disabled any additional, internal salting or padding mechanisms. The encrypted password will be the same every time, just like a MD5 or SHA1 hashed password would be. This way, the authentication system needs the public key, only. The private key is not required.

The private key is printed out, sealed and stored offline in the company's safe right after it is created. But when the accounts need to be converted later, it will allow access to the passwords.

Before we deploy this solution, I'd like to hear your opinion on this scheme. Any flaws in design? Any serious drawbacks compared to the symmetric encryption? Anything else we are missing?

Thank you very much in advance!

--

***Update:***
In response to Jack's arguments below, I'd like to add the relevant implementation details for our RSA-based "hashing" function:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");
rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] cryptRaw = rsa.doFinal(saltedPassword.getBytes());
```

Having quickly skimmed over the paper mentioned by Jack, I think I somewhat understand the importance of preprocessing such as OAEP. Would it be alright to **extend my original question** and ask if there is a way to apply the needed preprocessing and still have the function return the same output every time for each input, just as a regular hashing function would? I would accept an answer to that "bonus question" here. (Or should I make that a seperate question on SOF?)

--

***Update 2:***
I'm having a hard time accepting one of the present answers because I feel that none really does answer my question. But I no longer expect any more answers to come, so I'll accept the one that I feel is most constructive.

Comment: Converted to what, exactly? This seems very poorly justified for me, and a possible privacy concern for users.

Comment: @Cat: Sure, I agree. And believe me, we discussed those concerns at length. I the end, I'm confident that our solution will at least be an improvement to the current system that we are superseding and that is storing plain text passwords...

Comment: @cg: I can't speak to the security aspects, but I think this is a pretty clever solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding this as another answer because instead of answering the question asked (as I did in the first response) this is a workaround / alternative suggestion.

Simply put:

Use hashes BUT, whenever a user changes their password, also use your public key as follows:

- Generate a random symmetric key and use it to encrypt the timestamp, user identifier, and new password.

  - The timestamp is to ensure you don't mess up later when trying to find the current / most up-to-date password.
  - Username so that you know which account you're dealing with.
  - Password because it is a requirement.
- Store the encrypted text.
- Encrypt the symmetric key using your public key.
- Store the public key encrypted symmetric key with the encrypted text.
- Destroy the in-memory plaintext symmetric key, leaving only the public key encrypted key.

When you need to 'convert' the accounts using the current password, you use the private key and go through the password change records.  For each one:

- Using the private key, decrypt the symmetric key.
- Using the symmetric key, decrypt the record.
- If you have a record for this user already, compare timestamps, and keep the password that is most recent (discarding the older).
- Lather, rinse, repeat.

(Frankly I'm probably overdoing things by encrypting the timestamp and not leaving it plaintext, but I'm paranoid and I have a thing for timestamps.  Don't get me started.)

Since you only use the public key when changing passwords, speed isn't critical.  Also, you don't have to keep the records / files / data where the plaintext password is encrypted on the server the user uses for authentication.  This data can be archived or otherwise moved off regularly, as they aren't required for normal operations (that's what the hash is for).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your two elaborate answers! I think you have a valid point that I did not give much thought in this context. (Though I was generally aware that RSA encryption is much more expensive than MD5 hashing.) I believe this won't be an issue for our specific project but we will check more closely.

Comment: This does not really answer my question. But I'll accept it now as the most constructive contribution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in the question to give any reasonable answer. Anyway since you disable padding there is a good chance that one of the attacks described in the paper
"Why Textbook ElGamal and RSA Encryption are Insecure" by
D. Boneh, A. Joux, and P. Nguyen is applicable.

That is just a wild guess of course. Your proposal could be susceptible to a number of other attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the paper! Also, I updated my question above to provide some implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of answering your specific question, my main concern would have been management of the private key but given it's well and truly not accessible via any computer system breach, you're pretty well covered on that front.

I'd still question the logic of not using hashes though - this sounds like a classic [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it). A hashing process is deterministic so even if you decided to migrate systems in the future, so long as you can still use the same algorithm, you'll get the same result. Personally, I'd pick a strong hash algorithm, use a cryptographically strong, unique salt on each account and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We were actually missing this option in an other project, having to switch hashing algorithms (crypt->sha1). Personally, I'm inclined to agree that the conversion option will never be needed for this project. But ultimately, it is not up to me to decide in this case.

Comment: @cg: You leave the old hashes be and upgrade when user logs in, or changes password. Of course you need to use a storage scheme that includes algorithm info, but adding that to existing ones is trivial, too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems safe enough in terms of what is online but have you given full consideration to the offline storage. How easy will it be for people within your company to get access to the private key? How would you know if someone within your company had accessed the private key? How easy would it be for the private key to be destroyed (e.g. is the safe fireproof/waterproof, will the printed key become illegible over time etc).

You need to look at things such as split knowledge, dual control, tamper evident envelopes etc. As a minimum I think you need to print out two strings of data which when or'd together create the private key and then have one in your office and one in your customers office,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Patrick. I like the idea of splitting the private key! We will give that some consideration.

Answer (score 0):

One serious drawback I've not seen mentioned is the speed.

Symmetric encryption is generally much much faster than asymmetric.  That's normally fine because most people account for that in their designs (SSL, for example, only uses asymmetric encryption to share the symmetric key and checking certificates).  You're going to be doing asymmetric (slow) for every login, instead of cryptographic hashing (quite fast) or symmetric encryption (pretty snappy).  I don't know that it will impact performance, but it could.

As a point of comparison: on my machine an AES symmetric stream cipher encryption (aes-128 cbc) yields up to 188255kB/s.  That's a lot of passwords.  On the same machine, the peak performance for signatures per second (probably the closest approximation to your intended operation) using DSA with a 512 bit key (no longer used to sign SSL keys) is 8916.2 operations per second.  That difference is (roughly) a factor of a thousand assuming the signatures were using MD5 sized checksums.  Three orders of magnitude.

This direct comparison is probably not applicable directly to your situation, but my intention was to give you an idea of the comparative algorithmic complexity.

If you have cryptographic algorithms you would prefer to use or compare and you'd like to benchmark them on your system, I suggest the 'openssl speed' command for systems that have openssl builds.

You can also probably mitigate this concern with dedicated hardware designed to accelerate public key cryptographic operations.